# ORACLE BIPUBLISHER SQL Query taking too long to execute

Tags: sql, oracle

Following is the query

```
Select
pu.username,
ROLE.ROLE_NAME,
(
CASE
WHEN ((ROLE.ORG_ID IS NOT NULL) AND ROLE.ORG_ID=fabuv.BU_ID) THEN FABUV.BU_NAME
WHEN ((ROLE.LEDGER_ID IS NOT NULL) AND ROLE.LEDGER_ID=gl.LEDGER_ID) THEN GL.NAME
WHEN ((ROLE.BOOK_ID IS NOT NULL) AND ROLE.BOOK_ID=fbc.BOOK_CONTROL_ID) THEN FBC.BOOK_TYPE_NAME
WHEN ((ROLE.SET_ID IS NOT NULL) AND ROLE.SET_ID=fssv.SET_ID) THEN FSSV.SET_NAME
WHEN ((ROLE.INV_ORGANIZATION_ID IS NOT NULL) AND ROLE.INV_ORGANIZATION_ID=iop.ORGANIZATION_ID) THEN IOP.ORGANIZATION_CODE
WHEN ((ROLE.CST_ORGANIZATION_ID IS NOT NULL) AND ROLE.CST_ORGANIZATION_ID=ccov.COST_ORG_ID) THEN CCOV.COST_ORG_CODE
WHEN ((ROLE.ACCESS_SET_ID IS NOT NULL) AND ROLE.ACCESS_SET_ID=gas.ACCESS_SET_ID) THEN GAS.NAME
WHEN ((ROLE.CONTROL_BUDGET_ID IS NOT NULL) AND ROLE.CONTROL_BUDGET_ID=xcb.CONTROL_BUDGET_ID) THEN XCB.NAME
WHEN ((ROLE.INTERCO_ORG_ID IS NOT NULL) AND ROLE.INTERCO_ORG_ID=fio.INTERCO_ORG_ID) THEN FIO.INTERCO_ORG_NAME
ELSE 'NOT_APPLICABLE'
END
) "Security_Context_Value"
from
fusion.per_users pu,
fusion.FA_BOOK_CONTROLS FBC,
fusion.FUN_ALL_BUSINESS_UNITS_V FABUV,
fusion.XCC_CONTROL_BUDGETS XCB,
fusion.CST_COST_ORGS_V CCOV,
fusion.gl_access_sets GAS,
fusion.FUN_INTERCO_ORGANIZATIONS FIO,
fusion.INV_ORG_PARAMETERS iOP,
fusion.GL_LEDGERS GL,
fusion.RCS_MFG_PARAMETERS RMP,
fusion.FUN_USER_ROLE_DATA_ASGNMNTS ROLE,
fusion.FND_SETID_SETS_VL FSSV
where
1=1
and pu.USERNAME=:Username
AND ROLE.ORG_ID != NULL
OR ROLE.LEDGER_ID != NULL
OR ROLE.BOOK_ID != NULL
OR ROLE.SET_ID != NULL
OR ROLE.INV_ORGANIZATION_ID != NULL
OR ROLE.CST_ORGANIZATION_ID != NULL
OR ROLE.ACCESS_SET_ID != NULL
OR ROLE.CONTROL_BUDGET_ID != NULL
OR ROLE.INTERCO_ORG_ID != NULL
And pu.USER_GUID=role.USER_GUID
```

It is the query required to extract roles assigned to users with Security_Context and Value.
I have tried different combinations of using IS NOT NULL in place of '!=' but it also didnt help, again Username is not taken into consideration when if it run.

Comment: Many redundant `IS NOT NULL` there... Simply do `WHEN ROLE.ORG_ID = fabuv.BU_ID THEN...` etc.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed! (You miss several join conditions, and will end up with a huge cartesian product.)

Comment: AND goes before OR. You need parentheses!!!

Comment: Do  `IS NOT NULL` instead of `!= NULL`.

Comment: @Saubby You're missing loads and loads of join conditions. I second jarlh's suggestion to use ANSI join syntax - it makes it much clearer which join conditions you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after is something like:

```
SELECT pu.username,
     role.role_name,
     CASE WHEN ROLE.ORG_ID IS NOT NULL THEN FABUV.BU_NAME
            WHEN ROLE.LEDGER_ID IS NOT NULL THEN GL.NAME
            WHEN ROLE.BOOK_ID IS NOT NULL THEN FBC.BOOK_TYPE_NAME
            WHEN ROLE.SET_ID IS NOT NULL THEN FSSV.SET_NAME
            WHEN ROLE.INV_ORGANIZATION_ID IS NOT NULL THEN IOP.ORGANIZATION_CODE
            WHEN ROLE.CST_ORGANIZATION_ID IS NOT NULL THEN CCOV.COST_ORG_CODE
            WHEN ROLE.ACCESS_SET_ID IS NOT NULL THEN GAS.NAME
            WHEN ROLE.CONTROL_BUDGET_ID IS NOT NULL THEN XCB.NAME
            WHEN ROLE.INTERCO_ORG_ID IS NOT NULL THEN FIO.INTERCO_ORG_NAME
            ELSE 'NOT_APPLICABLE'
       END "Security_Context_Value"
FROM   fusion.per_users pu
       INNER JOIN fusion.fun_user_role_data_asgnmnts role ON pu.user_guid = role.user_guid
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fusion.fun_all_business_units_v fabuv ON role.org_id = fabuv.bu_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fusion.gl_ledgers gl ON role.ledger_id = gl.ledger_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fusion.fa_book_controls fbc ON role.book_id=fbc.book_control_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fusion.fnd_setid_sets_vl fssv ON role.SET_ID=fssv.SET_ID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fusion.inv_org_parameters iop ON role.inv_organization_id=iop.organization_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fusion.cst_cost_orgs_v ccov ON role.cst_organization_id=ccov.cost_org_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fusion.gl_access_sets gas ON role.access_set_id=gas.access_set_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fusion.xcc_control_budgets xcb ON role.control_budget_id=xcb.control_budget_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN fusion.fun_interco_organizations fio ON role.interco_org_id=fio.interco_org_id
WHERE  pu.username = :username
AND    COALESCE(role.org_id,
                role.ledger_id,
                role.book_id,
                role.set_id,
                role.inv_organization_id,
                role.cst_organization_id,
                role.access_set_id,
                role.control_budget_id,
                role.interco_org_id) IS NOT NULL;
```

Note the use of the ANSI join syntax, which forces you to add in join conditions (unless you explicitly request a cross join).

Your original query was doing a cross join between your `fabuv`, `gl`, `fbc`, etc tables, meaning each row in `fabuv` was being joined to all rows in gl, and each of the resultant rows was being joined to every row in the `fbc` table and so on... that's a *lot* of rows - e.g. if there are 100 rows in each of the `fabuv`, `gl`, `fbc`, etc tables, you're going to end up with 100 x 100 x 100 x ... which ends up being way too many rows.

I've take a guess as to what the join conditions should be, based on your case statement - n.b. the `rmp` table wasn't being referenced at all, so I've excluded it from the `from` clause.

I also used the `COALESCE` function to simplify your `where` clause - this function returns the first not-null value.

Comment: this is great Boneist,Thanks